# How to approve document collaboration for a subset of users

Tags: 2013, content-approval

This is a complicated requirement that is driving me a bit crazy and I was hoping someone could help me find a solution.

I'm using SharePoint 2013.

Imagine 3 collaborators and 1 very important (I'll fire you if its wrong) person who reaps the benefit of the collaboration. I'll call them 'Drafter', 'Approver', 'Advisor' and 'VIP'

The rules are

- They work collaboratively on a ***single*** Word document in a document library
- Drafter, Approver and Advisor may edit the document
- Advisor tells VIP when the work is ready review
- Advisor can also suggest changes that Drafter and Approver would have to implement
- Drafter's work ***must always*** be approved by Approver before Advisor sees it
- Edits from anyone happen concurrently

The last 2 points are the tricky ones. It basically would work the same as a Pull Request in github where the document is branched, reviewed then merged back into master.

so instead of

```
+v1---+v2---+v3---+v4
```

it would work like

```
+v1---+v2---+v3---+v4
  \          /        
   ----------   <- Drafter's work isn't included until merged
```

I thought at first that I could send the document to a Document Site but it doesn't seem have any mechanism to merge back to the original document. From the Document Site  using the command on the Document Ribbon I am able to Send the Document to the original Document Library but that squashes interim edits.

So I was wondering how to make this work and what the permissions would need to be for a group not to see pending stuff edited by others